# How to club multiple sms notification in android just like default sms application do?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

I am building a SMS based android application. till now i have completed the module to receive SMS and display its notification.But for every Received SMS a notification is created in notification area.

I want to club the notification if there are any unread/unseen notification just like default sms application do. is there any way to perform this ??